# Changing Terms in an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Beginner at Java here, I'm trying to get different terms in an arrayList to add up together if they have the same element value(character value) and add the new term to an new arraylist. I keep getting an error where it says c.molecular has <1> component expected, but was <0>.

Here's my code.

The method .getElement returns the character value element of the Term in the Arraylist Term, and the method .nextElement just gives the alphabetically smallest Term in the arraylist terms.

```
public void makeMolecular()
    { 
        terms = new ArrayList<Term>();
        molecular = new ArrayList<Term>();



        for(int m = 0; m <terms.size() ; m++){

            molecular.add(nextElement());
            terms.remove(m);

        }
        for(int a =0; a < molecular.size()-1; a++){
            if(molecular.get(a).getElement() ==molecular.get(a+1).getElement()){
                molecular.remove(a);
                molecular.remove(a+1);
                char element2 = molecular.get(a).getElement();
                int number2= molecular.get(a).getAtoms() + molecular.get(a+1).getAtoms();
                Term unyielding = new Term(element2, number2 );
                molecular.add  (unyielding);
                  terms = new ArrayList<Term>(molecular);
            }
        }
```

Comment: which line is this error at:?? ***c.molecular has <1>...***

Comment: to be honest, I don't really know...

Comment: it doesn't really specify

Comment: Post the exact and complete error message you get. Don't paraphrase.

Answer (score 0):

`for(int a =0; a < molecular.size()-1; a++)`
can u change the above line to this 
`for(int a =0; a < molecular.size(); a++)`

let me know if you get any errors after changing the line